# How to sort out files after opening directory

Tags: php, sorting, directory

I have this code which reads the files from a specified directory, and outputs the contents into a drop down menu. The problem is that all the files are not listed in alphanumerical order. They're all jumbled up! Anyway, here is the code:

```
<form name="index1">
<select name="menu" onchange="jump(this.form)">
<?php

$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<option value="">Choose a chapter or volume</option>';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "afile.php")){      
        $name = basename($file,".php");
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$name</option>";
    }
}           
?>
</select>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your issue :

```
<form name="index1">
<select name="menu" onchange="jump(this.form)">
<?php

    echo '<option value="">Choose a chapter or volume</option>';

    // Get an array of files in the "$dirname" path
    // The array should be sorted by name ascending
    $files = array_filter(glob($dirname. '/*'), 'is_file');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file != "afile.php") {
            $name = basename($file,".php");
            echo "<option value=".$file.">$name</option>";
        }
    }

?>
</select>
</form>
```

You can check the [glob](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php) function which is very helpful !

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo:

you wrote:

```
foreach(files as $file) {
```

but it should be:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
```

Comment: I know you're a new user without comment privileges, but this can't really be seen as an answer.